# Why is my flutter http response json decoding not returning foreign language characters

Tags: flutter, dart

I am doing an http request with Flutter. The response body text for foreign language is broken.
Here is the result for flutter:
[image]

Of which it should be something like this:
[image]

The language in question is Korean.
Here is my http request code:

```
  fetchJobs() async {
   var response = await http.get(Global.apiurl + 'jobs/');
    if (response != null && response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      JobResultModel jsonResponse =
          JobResultModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      return jsonResponse.results;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

end use

```
jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))
```

instead of

```
jsonDecode(response.body)
```